# Can the heap manager be identified from memory block?

Tags: c++, memory-management, dll, heap-memory, reference-counting

I have an application that consists of a host program and a few plugins. The plugins are implemented in dlls that can be dynamically loaded and unloaded. The code of the plugins (inside the dlls) allocate memory for objects and pass the pointers to the host program. These objects are allocated on the dll heap and there is no way to change the interface to use a specialized memory allocation function.

Is there a way for the host program to detect on which heap manager an object has been allocated? I want to implement some kind of reference counting for the dll. As long as the host program still uses memory from the dll, the dll cannot be unloaded. That means I would like to track from the host program who (which plugin) allocated a memory block (objects that are kept in various lists inside the host). The current interface includes a call to unload a dll. This call should schedule for unload, but only execute it once the host is finished using the memory.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: You are better off tracking the dll when the pointer is passed to the host program. There are functions in Windows that allow you to snapshot the heap and walk it but they often lead to terrible performance. You can look at ["Traversing the heap"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd299432(v=vs.85).aspx) for some information but this should be used as a debugging mechanism alone.

Comment: Are you sure. MS stopped this being the default behavior about 10 years ago. Nowadays the default is to use a shared heap. You have to do extra work for this behavior to be the norm.

Comment: So the plugins never allocate memory that they do not return a pointer to the memory to the host program?  The MSVC runtime has no heap objects that represent the CRT heaps.

Comment: I used MemoryValidator to check everything. Upon unload all allocated memory of the dll becomes invalid as well.(I thought that is also the reason why there is no memory leak if a dll doesn't properly release all its memory)In my temporary fix I keep all dlls loaded until the host schedules for quitting. At this point all internal lists are cleared. Only afterwards I unload the dlls,but this means I have to keep dlls open even if they are not needed any more.

Comment: I am still using VS2010 on WinXP with latest updates.

Comment: @Loki Astari, can't an individual dll do a HeapCreate and HeapAlloc ? Can you please explain what you meant by your comment ?

Comment: @ArunMK: Originally DevStud statically linked the runtime thus each DLL (and the application) had its own heap. Thus memory allocated by a DLL must be freed by the same DLL. This turned out to be a complete nightmare so MS changed the default so the runtime is dynamically linked which results in all DLL (and the application) using the same runtime library and thus the same heap. Now you can manually create extra heaps (but that's extra work) so by default modern programs use the same heap and it does not matter who allocates or de-allocates memory. But you can use other heaps if you want.